# Do Polars dataframes need to be formatted a certain way to be used with scikit-learn models?

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, python-polars

I've been working through a notebook on Kaggle that used Pandas, and I wanted to refactor it to Polars.

The dataframes I'm working with look like this:

`X_train`

| Pclass (i64) | Sex (i16) | Age (i32) | Fare (i16) | Embarked (i16) | title (i16) | family_size (i64) | is_alone (i64) | age*class (i64) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

`shape: (891,9)`

`y_train`

| Survived (i64) |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| ... |

`shape: (891,1)`

Kaggle has me creating a logistic regression with the following code:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

It's my understanding that Polars dataframes don't work with sklearn, so I modified `X_train` and `y_train` to be numpy ndarrays like so:

```
logreg.fit(X_train.to_numpy(),y_train.to_numpy())
```

but then I get the following error:

```
>>> logreg.fit(X_train.to_numpy(),y_train.to_numpy())
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:993: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
LogisticRegression()
```

I was going to try saying `y_train.transpose()`, but there's no mention of needing to reshape the Pandas dataframe so I'm wondering if a transpose is really necessary, or if I'm doing something else wrong.

Edit:

I added the `numpy.ravel()` function like this `logreg.fit(X_train.to_numpy(),y_train.to_numpy().ravel())` and it seems to have worked, but now when I say
`y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test.to_numpy())` I get the following error

```
>>>y_pred= logreg.predict(X_test.to_numpy())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 425, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 407, in decision_function
    X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 566, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 800, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 114, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

My `X_test` df is the same as `X_train` with the addition of a `Survived` feature.

| Survived (i64) | Pclass (i64) | Sex (i16) | Age (i32) | Fare (i16) | Embarked (i16) | title (i16) | family_size (i64) | is_alone (i64) | age*class (i64) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

`shape (418,10)`

Comment: `.ravel()` is a numpy method so the error is suggesting you use `y_train.to_numpy().ravel()`

Comment: `y_train.to_series()` should also work.

Comment: It seems like you have null values. They are converted to `NaN` on a `to_numpy` call, which this specific `sklearn` algorithm cannot deal with. Make sure you remove missing values.

Comment: Looks like you're using the Titanic dataset - there's examples of that using polars on Kaggle, I suggest you search and check them out

Comment: @ritchie46 you were right. I didn't realize I needed to drop the null target column from my testing dataset. And for others reading this, @jqurious was right about needing to say ```y_train.to_numpy().ravel()```.